# Set UIView height based on inner view height using constraints

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have one `UIView` and inside that, *N* `UILabels` which are laid out relative to each other.

The containing `UIView` has a background color, I want to extend the `UIView` to be high enough to cover all labels inside it, so the background color is behind them all.

(I'm embedding them in a UIView so I can have the labels inset from the view edges.)

Is there away to make the `UIView`'s height expand to fill its content? I can't figure it from the constraint options, it seems like its all relative to superviews.

Normally I'd just work out the frame sizes programatically in `viewDidAppear` but those are getting reset by the constraints system, AFAIK.

Comment: Is N fixed at compile time?

Comment: Yes. I think I actually worked it out though. I had the labels height set manually from when I drag-dropped and resized it. Deleting the height constraint on the `UILabel` made it size to fit content, which causes its superview to resize too. At least I think that's the case, I'm new to constraints.

Comment: If you are new to autolayout, I highly recommend watching these videos  from WWDC 2012: [Session 202 - Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202), [Session 228 - Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228), and [Session 232 - Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I actually worked it out though.

I had the labels height set manually from when I drag-dropped and resized it. Deleting the height constraint on the UILabel made it size to fit content, which causes its superview to resize too. At least I think that's the case, I'm new to constraints.

Will leave the question up since it will probably bite someone else too.